# linux script output to console 1

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm running a script using cron job every Sunday night on my Linux PC. When I log in as root I would like the output of this last script execution to be displayed.

Here is a script `msg.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e /user/script/$start.sh ]
then 
   echo " starting  service "
else
   echo " service not started " 
   echo " Please check the start.sh file or manually start the service "
fi
exit 0
```

Its output:

```
starting  service
```

or

```
service not started
Please check the start.sh file or manually start the service
```

How can I make this output appear when I log in?

Answer (score 2):

In your cron job, save the output to some file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# drop the contents of a log file and create a new one
LOGFILE=/root/cronjob_status.log
date > $LOGFILE

if [ -e /user/script/$start.sh ]
then 
   echo " starting  service " >> $LOGFILE
else
   echo " service not started " >> $LOGFILE
   echo " Please check the start.sh file or manuly start the service " >> $LOGFILE
fi
exit 0
```

In your `/root/.bash_profile` which is executed when you log in as root (assuming that your shell is `/bin/bash`), `cat` that file:

```
cat /root/cronjob_status.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Saving to a file (afenster's answer) is a good solution.

Alternatively, you can set the `MAILTO` variable in the cron configuration file. Cron will then send any output from the command it runs to that address.